# Bootstrap 3 - Tab-Pages creating white spaces

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 for a project and I'm having a problem with tabs... and this is only happening in one of the pages...

I've 2 tabs, and everything loads fine except for the fact the second tab (not active) loads as well, as a huge white space under the active tab content. I'm using tabs in other parts of the site (backoffice) and I've had no problems or whatsoever so far... I've checked for open HTML brackets but I've found none... Can you have a look at what's happening?

Thanks!

Website: http://www.jomall.org/v2/ (look between at the footer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo on the second div

```
<div class="tab-page" id="contacts">
```

should be

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="contacts">
```

Comment: nah when you look at something too long sometimes you just don't see the mistake!